# first tabPanel not rendering the output in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, linear-regression, reactive

Below is a reprex code for a Shiny app that creates 3 tabPanels on the main panel. But each time I run first tabPanel not rendering the output. However if I switch to the second/third tabPanel and come back to the first tabPanel the results are displayed. How do I make the first tabPanel to show the output without doing this switch tabs from 2 back to 1 or 3 back to 1?

**EDITED: A small rearrangement of a parenthesis so that the correlation coefficient answer is displayed.**

```
library(bslib)
library(car)
library(moments)
library(nortest)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)

options(scipen = 999) # options(scipen = 0)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
           
  navbarPage(title = div(span("Reg & Cor", style = "color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:18pt")),

                tabPanel(title = "Methods",
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      withMathJax(),
                      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                      id = "sideBar", 
                      selectInput(
                        inputId = "dropDownMenu",
                        label = strong("Choose Statistical Topic"),
                        choices = c("A", "B", "C", "Regression and Correlation"),
                        selected = "Regression and Correlation",
                      ),
                      
                      conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "input.dropDownMenu == 'Regression and Correlation'",
                        
                        id = "RegCorPanel",
                        
                        textAreaInput("x", label = strong("x (Independent Variable)"), value = "635, 644, 711, 708, 836, 820, 810, 870, 856, 923", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", rows = 3),
                        textAreaInput("y", label = strong("y (Dependent Variable)"), value = "100, 93, 88, 84, 77, 75, 74, 63, 57, 55", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", rows = 3),
                        
                        radioButtons(inputId = "regressioncorrelation", label = strong("Analyze Data Using"), selected = c("Simple Linear Regression"), choices = c("Simple Linear Regression", "Correlation Coefficient"), inline = TRUE),

                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "input.regressioncorrelation == 'Correlation Coefficient'",
                          
                          checkboxInput("pearson", "Pearson's Product-Moment Correlation (r)"),
                        ),
                        
                        actionButton(inputId = "goRegression", label = "Calculate",
                                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                        actionButton("resetRegCor", label = "Reset Values",
                                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4") #, onclick = "history.go(0)"
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                    mainPanel(
                      div(id = "RegCorMP",

                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "input.regressioncorrelation == 'Simple Linear Regression'",

                            tabsetPanel(id = 'tabSet',
                                tabPanel(id = "SLR", title = "Simple Linear Regression",
                                     plotOutput("scatterplot", width = "500px"),
                                     br(),
                                     
                                     verbatimTextOutput("linearRegression"),
                                     br(),
                                     
                                     verbatimTextOutput("confintLinReg"),
                                     br(),
                                     
                                     verbatimTextOutput("anovaLinReg"),
                                 ),
                                 
                                tabPanel(id = "normality", title = "Normality of Residuals",

                                     verbatimTextOutput("AndersonDarlingTest"),
                                     br(),
                                     
                                     verbatimTextOutput("KolmogorovSmirnovTest"),
                                     br(),
                                     
                                     verbatimTextOutput("ShapiroTest"),
                                ),
                                
                                tabPanel(id = "resid", title = "Residual Plots",
                                    
                                    plotOutput("qqplot", width = "500px"),

                                    plotOutput("moreplots", width = "500px"),
                                ),
                          ),
                        ),
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "input.regressioncorrelation == 'Correlation Coefficient'",

                            conditionalPanel(
                              condition = "input.pearson == 1",
                              
                              verbatimTextOutput("PearsonEstimate"),

                              verbatimTextOutput("PearsonCorTest"),

                              verbatimTextOutput("PearsonConfInt"),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ) # RegCorMP
                    ) # mainPanel
                  ), # sidebarLayout
                ), # Methods Panel
        )
  )
  
server <- function(input, output) {

    # String List to Numeric List
    createNumLst <- function(text) {
      text <- gsub("","", text)
      split <- strsplit(text, ",", fixed = FALSE)[[1]]
      as.numeric(split)
    }

    observeEvent(input$goRegression, {
      
      datx <- createNumLst(input$x)
      daty <- createNumLst(input$y)
      
      if(anyNA(datx) | length(datx)<2 | anyNA(daty) | length(daty)<2){
        # output$linearRegression <- renderPrint({ 
        # "Invalid input or not enough observations"
        #   })
        print("Invalid input or not enough observations")
      }
      else{
          if(input$regressioncorrelation == "Simple Linear Regression")
          {
            model <- lm(daty ~ datx)

          output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
            plot(datx, daty, main = "Scatter Plot", xlab = "Independent Variable, x", ylab = "Dependent Variable, y", pch = 19) +
              abline(lm(daty ~ datx), col = "blue")
          })
            
          output$linearRegression <- renderPrint({ 
            summary(model)
          })
          
          output$confintLinReg <- renderPrint({ 
            confint(model)
          })
            
          output$anovaLinReg <- renderPrint({ 
              anova(model)
          })

          output$AndersonDarlingTest <- renderPrint({ 
            ad.test(model$residuals)
          })
          
          output$KolmogorovSmirnovTest <- renderPrint({ 
            ks.test(model$residuals, "pnorm")
          })

          output$ShapiroTest <- renderPrint({ 
            shapiro.test(model$residuals) 
          })
          
          output$qqplot <- renderPlot({
            qqPlot(model$residuals, main = "Q-Q Plot", xlab = "Z Scores",  ylab = "Residuals", pch = 19) 
          })
          
          output$moreplots <- renderPlot({
            par(mfrow = c(2,2))
            plot(model, which=1:4, pch = 19)
          })
        }

        else if(input$regressioncorrelation == "Correlation Coefficient")
        {
          output$PearsonEstimate <- renderPrint({ 
            cor.test(datx, daty, method = "pearson")$estimate
          })
          
          output$PearsonCorTest <- renderPrint({ 
            cor.test(datx, daty, method = "pearson")
          })

          output$PearsonConfInt <- renderPrint({ 
            cor.test(datx, daty, method = "pearson")$conf.int
          })
        } # Correlation
      }
    }) # input$goRegression

    observeEvent(input$goRegression, {
      show(id = "RegCorMP")
      showTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Simple Linear Regression')
      showTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Normality of Residuals')
      showTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Residual Plots')
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$resetRegCor, {
      # hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Simple Linear Regression')
      # hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Normality of Residuals')
      # hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Residual Plots')
      hide(id = "RegCorMP")
      shinyjs::reset("RegCorPanel")
    })

    observe(
      hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Simple Linear Regression')
    )

    observe(
      hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Normality of Residuals')
    )

    observe(
      hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Residual Plots')
    )
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the last 3 observe events:

uncomment them then it will work:

```
library(car)
library(moments)
library(nortest)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(bslib)

options(scipen = 999) # options(scipen = 0)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
                
                navbarPage(title = div(span("Reg & Cor", style = "color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:18pt")),
                           
                           tabPanel(title = "Methods",
                                    sidebarLayout(
                                      sidebarPanel(
                                        withMathJax(),
                                        shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                                        id = "sideBar", 
                                        selectInput(
                                          inputId = "dropDownMenu",
                                          label = strong("Choose Statistical Topic"),
                                          choices = c("A", "B", "C", "Regression and Correlation"),
                                          selected = "Regression and Correlation",
                                        ),
                                        
                                        conditionalPanel(
                                          condition = "input.dropDownMenu == 'Regression and Correlation'",
                                          
                                          id = "RegCorPanel",
                                          
                                          textAreaInput("x", label = strong("x (Independent Variable)"), value = "635, 644, 711, 708, 836, 820, 810, 870, 856, 923", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", rows = 3),
                                          textAreaInput("y", label = strong("y (Dependent Variable)"), value = "100, 93, 88, 84, 77, 75, 74, 63, 57, 55", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points", rows = 3),
                                          
                                          radioButtons(inputId = "regressioncorrelation", label = strong("Analyze Data Using"), selected = c("Simple Linear Regression"), choices = c("Simple Linear Regression", "Correlation Coefficient"), inline = TRUE),
                                          
                                          conditionalPanel(
                                            condition = "input.regressioncorrelation == 'Correlation Coefficient'",
                                            
                                            checkboxInput("pearson", "Pearson's Product-Moment Correlation (r)"),
                                          ),
                                          
                                          actionButton(inputId = "goRegression", label = "Calculate",
                                                       style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                                          actionButton("resetRegCor", label = "Reset Values",
                                                       style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4") #, onclick = "history.go(0)"
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      
                                      mainPanel(
                                        div(id = "RegCorMP",
                                            
                                            conditionalPanel(
                                              condition = "input.regressioncorrelation == 'Simple Linear Regression'",
                                              
                                              tabsetPanel(id = 'tabSet',
                                                          tabPanel(id = "SLR", title = "Simple Linear Regression",
                                                                   plotOutput("scatterplot", width = "500px"),
                                                                   br(),
                                                                   
                                                                   verbatimTextOutput("linearRegression"),
                                                                   br(),
                                                                   
                                                                   verbatimTextOutput("confintLinReg"),
                                                                   br(),
                                                                   
                                                                   verbatimTextOutput("anovaLinReg"),
                                                          ),
                                                          
                                                          tabPanel(id = "normality", title = "Normality of Residuals",
                                                                   
                                                                   verbatimTextOutput("AndersonDarlingTest"),
                                                                   br(),
                                                                   
                                                                   verbatimTextOutput("KolmogorovSmirnovTest"),
                                                                   br(),
                                                                   
                                                                   verbatimTextOutput("ShapiroTest"),
                                                          ),
                                                          
                                                          tabPanel(id = "resid", title = "Residual Plots",
                                                                   
                                                                   plotOutput("qqplot", width = "500px"),
                                                                   
                                                                   plotOutput("moreplots", width = "500px"),
                                                          ),
                                              ),
                                              
                                              conditionalPanel(
                                                condition = "input.regressioncorrelation == 'Correlation Coefficient'",
                                                
                                                conditionalPanel(
                                                  condition = "input.pearson == 1",
                                                  
                                                  verbatimTextOutput("PearsonEstimate"),
                                                  
                                                  verbatimTextOutput("PearsonCorTest"),
                                                  
                                                  verbatimTextOutput("PearsonConfInt"),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        ) # RegCorMP
                                      ) # mainPanel
                                    ), # sidebarLayout
                           ), # Methods Panel
                )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # String List to Numeric List
  createNumLst <- function(text) {
    text <- gsub("","", text)
    split <- strsplit(text, ",", fixed = FALSE)[[1]]
    as.numeric(split)
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$goRegression, {
    
    datx <- createNumLst(input$x)
    daty <- createNumLst(input$y)
    
    if(anyNA(datx) | length(datx)<2 | anyNA(daty) | length(daty)<2){
      # output$linearRegression <- renderPrint({ 
      # "Invalid input or not enough observations"
      #   })
      print("Invalid input or not enough observations")
    }
    else{
      if(input$regressioncorrelation == "Simple Linear Regression")
      {
        model <- lm(daty ~ datx)
        
        output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
          plot(datx, daty, main = "Scatter Plot", xlab = "Independent Variable, x", ylab = "Dependent Variable, y", pch = 19) +
            abline(lm(daty ~ datx), col = "blue")
        })
        
        output$linearRegression <- renderPrint({ 
          summary(model)
        })
        
        output$confintLinReg <- renderPrint({ 
          confint(model)
        })
        
        output$anovaLinReg <- renderPrint({ 
          anova(model)
        })
        
        output$AndersonDarlingTest <- renderPrint({ 
          ad.test(model$residuals)
        })
        
        output$KolmogorovSmirnovTest <- renderPrint({ 
          ks.test(model$residuals, "pnorm")
        })
        
        output$ShapiroTest <- renderPrint({ 
          shapiro.test(model$residuals) 
        })
        
        output$qqplot <- renderPlot({
          qqPlot(model$residuals, main = "Q-Q Plot", xlab = "Z Scores",  ylab = "Residuals", pch = 19) 
        })
        
        output$moreplots <- renderPlot({
          par(mfrow = c(2,2))
          plot(model, which=1:4, pch = 19)
        })
      }
      
      else if(input$regressioncorrelation == "Correlation Coefficient")
      {
        output$PearsonEstimate <- renderPrint({ 
          cor.test(datx, daty, method = "pearson")$estimate
        })
        
        output$PearsonCorTest <- renderPrint({ 
          cor.test(datx, daty, method = "pearson")
        })
        
        output$PearsonConfInt <- renderPrint({ 
          cor.test(datx, daty, method = "pearson")$conf.int
        })
      } # Correlation
    }
  }) # input$goRegression
  
  observeEvent(input$goRegression, {
    show(id = "RegCorMP")
    showTab(inputId = 'tabset', target = 'Simple Linear Regression')
    showTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Normality of Residuals')
    showTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Residual Plots')
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$resetRegCor, {
    # hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Simple Linear Regression')
    # hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Normality of Residuals')
    # hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Residual Plots')
    hide(id = "RegCorMP")
    shinyjs::reset("RegCorPanel")
  })
  
  # observe(
  #   hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Simple Linear Regression')
  # )
  
  # observe(
  #   hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Normality of Residuals')
  # )
  # 
  # observe(
  #   hideTab(inputId = 'tabSet', target = 'Residual Plots')
  # )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This solved the problem. I am also going to set `selected = character(0),` for the radio button. The problem with none of the radio button selected is the Calculate button would need to first validate of one of the choices is selected otherwise it is throwing an error.

Comment: After clicking Calculate button for the Regression and Correlation and selecting a different dropdown option (say A or B or C) it is not clearing the mainPanel to blank screen like I want. The three tabPanels get carried over to the other dropdown as well. Is there a way to always clear what's on the mainPanel each I switch to a different dropdown menu?

Comment: This would be a good new question. But you should shorten your reproducible example to smallest possible example with removing all irrelevant parts.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Will post a new question with a smaller reprex code.